# Module (Riot) not Found, yet riotjs is installed and working

Tags: webpack-dev-server, riot.js

I do have riot and riot-cli installed globally. I have tested both from the command line. In fact I have another project where riot is watching and pre-compiling normally.

This is a webpack setup and this is the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'riot' in 
'c:\Users\...\www\riot\src'
@ ./src/index.js 3:11-26
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http... ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.tags/sample-output.tag' in 'c:\Users\...\www\riot\src'
@ ./src/index.js 4:0-34
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http... ./src/index.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

here is the index file:

```
var riot = require('riot')
require('.tags/sample-output.tag')

document.addEventlistner('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    riot.mount('sample-output')
})
```

here is the webpack.config

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output:{
        path:__dirname,
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query:{
                    presets:['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tag$/,
                loader: 'tag',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Note we do not use [Solved] title devices here - click the tick mark adjacent to your preferred answer instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(SOLVED) I found the answer.

Basically my called my project folder 'riot', then when I ran `npm init -y` with the **`-y`** flag (because I am lazy).

It named my project '**riot**' of course! and THAT was the source of the problem.

For more info see this: http://thisdavej.com/node-newbie-error-npm-refusing-to-install-package-as-a-dependency-of-itself/